# How language agnostic is Magic Maze on Mars

Tags: untagged

I'm considering buying Magic Maze on Mars. It is out of stock in my local game store (which is always my first option, they need and deserve my support). So the next option I checked was directly from the publisher at https://sitdown-games.com/produit/magic-maze-on-mars.

At the moment they have only the French version available. I speak maybe a dozen or two words of French. I have been able to find an English version of the rule book online, which might make it worthwhile to buy the French version of the game anyhow. But that depends on the rest of the game. Excluding the rule booklet, would there be any other French in the game?

I may be looking for other ways of getting a copy of the game, but that's not what the question is about. It is solely about whether a French copy is playable without having to learn any French.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BoardGameGeek says "[no necessary in-game text](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/283135/magic-maze-mars)" so you should be fine if you've got an English rulebook.

Comment: Well, that's a nice and useful thing I didn't know BGG did. Thanks a lot.